Using Apps Script to automate sending multiple emails from a google sheet, each with a different specific pdf attachment stored in Google Drive
This works to send automated emails from the same Google sheet, but when I added lines 9, 18 and 21(attachments part) it keeps returning

Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.
SendMails   @ Code.gs:21

Google Drive API has been added
 1  function SendMails() {

 3  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 4  var wrkShtEmailIDs= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Email_ID");
 5  var wrkShtMessage= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Mail_Details");
 6  var subject = wrkShtMessage.getRange('A2').getValue();
 7  var message = wrkShtMessage.getRange('B2').getValue();
 8
 9  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
10
11
12  for (var i=41;i<43;i++){
13
14  var fname = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('A' + i).getValue();
15  var lname = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('B' + i).getValue();
16  var emailAddress = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('C' + i).getValue();
17  var fileName = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('D' + i).getDisplayValue();
18  var file = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
19  var finalmsg = "";
20  finalmsg = fname + "\n" + message;
21 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, finalmsg, {attachments:[file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]})
22  }
23  }

I don't really know what else to try, I initially was using .getFolderByName in place of getFolderById on line 9, but got the same result.

Your fileName isn't gonna match with what's in the folder because you are using getDisplayValue() which will return the cell value with all its formatting. Simply use getValue() and also check if the file even exists.


function SendMails() {
  const wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const wrkShtEmailIDs = wrkBk.getSheetByName("Email_ID");
  const wrkShtMessage = wrkBk.getSheetByName("Mail_Details");
  const subject = wrkShtMessage.getRange('A2').getValue();
  const message = wrkShtMessage.getRange('B2').getValue();

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

  for (let i = 41; i < 43; i++) {
    let fname = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('A' + i).getValue();
    let lname = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('B' + i).getValue();
    let emailAddress = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('C' + i).getValue();
    let fileName = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange('D' + i).getValue();
    let files = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);

    if (files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next();
      let finalmsg = fname + "\n" + message;
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, finalmsg, {
        attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
      });
    } else {
      Logger.log('No file found with the name: ' + fileName);
    }
  }
}



I also suggest using GmailApp class in case you need more options.
P.S. I couldn't stand the use of var so you are welcome :-)

I initially tried just changing getDisplay value to getValue, which yielded the same error.   I then just trashed my entire script and used the one you recommended.  It showed me that one of the filenames in the list I was trying to send was named differently than what was listed on my spreadsheet.  I changed the filename and everything worked correctly and the mail was sent with attachement just as intended.  I can't thank you enough.  I greatly appreciate your help.

Since you haven't shared the sheet and the folder content, we can't tell you what is happening exactly.
I suggest you add Logger.log(filename); after line 17. The next time that you run the script, this will log the filename value, which will help you know what is happening and verify that the values read match file names contained by the folder.
You might also find it helpful to add Logger.log(folder.getName()); after line 9 to verify that your script is using the correct folder ID.
